# Missing libraries when installing qt-everywhere for cross-compiling on arm

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, qtembedded

I'm trying to install qt everywhere for cross compiling code. I'm using this command to configure it:

```
./configure -embedded arm -xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++ -qt-kbd-linuxinput -qt-mouse-tslib -opensource -verbose -R /home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/lib
```

But I get the following error. I tried installing the libraries it can't find, like egl, using apt-get, but it says unable to fetch archives.

> Creating qmake. Please wait...
>   make: Nothing to be done for `first'.
>   floatmath auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0`pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`-c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o floatmath.o floatmath.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   floatmath.cpp:44: warning: unused parameter 'argc'
>   floatmath.cpp:44: warning: unused parameter 'argv'
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0`pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`-Wl,-O1 -o floatmath floatmath.o    -L/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/lib
>
>   /usr/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [floatmath] Error 1
>   floatmath disabled.
>   mmx auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0`pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`-c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -mmmx -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o mmx.o mmx.cpp
>   cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-mmmx"
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   make: *** [mmx.o] Error 1
>   mmx disabled.
>   3dnow auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0`pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`-c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -m3dnow -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o 3dnow.o 3dnow.cpp
>   cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-m3dnow"
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   make: *** [3dnow.o] Error 1
>   3dnow disabled.
>   sse auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0`pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`-c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -msse -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o sse.o sse.cpp
>   cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-msse"
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   make: *** [sse.o] Error 1
>   sse disabled.
>   sse2 auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0`pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`-c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -msse2 -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o sse2.o sse2.cpp
>   cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-msse2"
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   make: *** [sse2.o] Error 1
>   sse2 disabled.
>   neon auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0`pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`-c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -mfpu=neon -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o neon.o neon.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   In file included from neon.cpp:42:
>   /usr/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include/arm_neon.h:35:2: error: #error You must enable NEON instructions (e.g. -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon) to use arm_neon.h
>   neon.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
>   neon.cpp:46: error: 'int32x4_t' was not declared in this scope
>   neon.cpp:46: error: expected`;' before 'null'
>   neon.cpp:49: error: 'null' was not declared in this scope
>   neon.cpp:49: error: 'vst1q_lane_s32' was not declared in this scope
>   make: *** [neon.o] Error 1
>   neon disabled.
>   zlib auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o zlib.o zlib.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -Wl,-O1 -o zlib zlib.o    -L/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/lib -lz 
>   /usr/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [zlib] Error 1
>   zlib disabled.
>   libjpeg auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o libjpeg.o libjpeg.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -Wl,-O1 -o libjpeg libjpeg.o    -L/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/lib -ljpeg 
>   /usr/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [libjpeg] Error 1
>   libjpeg disabled.
>   libtiff auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o libtiff.o libtiff.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   libtiff.cpp:42:20: error: tiffio.h: No such file or directory
>   libtiff.cpp:50:6: error: #error "Required libtiff not found"
>   libtiff.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
>   libtiff.cpp:57: error: 'tdata_t' was not declared in this scope
>   libtiff.cpp:57: error: expected `;' before 'buffer'
>   libtiff.cpp:58: error: 'buffer' was not declared in this scope
>   libtiff.cpp:58: error: '_TIFFfree' was not declared in this scope
>   libtiff.cpp:62: error: 'TIFFReadRGBAImageOriented' was not declared in this scope
>   make: *** [libtiff.o] Error 1
>   libtiff disabled.
>   libmng auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0`pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`-c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o libmng.o libmng.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   libmng.cpp:42:20: error: libmng.h: No such file or directory
>   libmng.cpp:50:2: error: #error System libmng version is less than 1.0.9; using built-in version instead.
>   libmng.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
>   libmng.cpp:46: error: 'mng_handle' was not declared in this scope
>   libmng.cpp:46: error: expected`;' before 'hMNG'
>   libmng.cpp:47: error: 'hMNG' was not declared in this scope
>   libmng.cpp:47: error: 'mng_cleanup' was not declared in this scope
>   make: *** [libmng.o] Error 1
>   libmng disabled.
>   libpng auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o libpng.o libpng.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -Wl,-O1 -o libpng libpng.o    -L/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/lib -lpng 
>   /usr/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [libpng] Error 1
>   libpng disabled.
>   DB2 auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o db2.o db2.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   db2.cpp:42:20: error: sqlcli.h: No such file or directory
>   db2.cpp:43:21: error: sqlcli1.h: No such file or directory
>   make: *** [db2.o] Error 1
>   DB2 disabled.
>   InterBase auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o ibase.o ibase.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   ibase.cpp:42:19: error: ibase.h: No such file or directory
>   make: *** [ibase.o] Error 1
>   InterBase disabled.
>   MySQL (thread-safe) auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o mysql.o ../mysql/mysql.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   ../mysql/mysql.cpp:42:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
>   make: *** [mysql.o] Error 1
>   MySQL (thread-safe) disabled.
>   MySQL (thread-unsafe) auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o mysql.o mysql.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   mysql.cpp:42:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
>   make: *** [mysql.o] Error 1
>   MySQL (thread-unsafe) disabled.
>   OCI auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o oci.o oci.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   oci.cpp:42:17: error: oci.h: No such file or directory
>   make: *** [oci.o] Error 1
>   OCI disabled.
>   ODBC auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o odbc.o odbc.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   odbc.cpp:42:17: error: sql.h: No such file or directory
>   odbc.cpp:43:20: error: sqlext.h: No such file or directory
>   make: *** [odbc.o] Error 1
>   ODBC disabled.
>   iODBC auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o iodbc.o iodbc.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   iodbc.cpp:42:17: error: sql.h: No such file or directory
>   iodbc.cpp:43:20: error: sqlext.h: No such file or directory
>   make: *** [iodbc.o] Error 1
>   iODBC disabled.
>   PostgreSQL auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o psql.o psql.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   psql.cpp:42:22: error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
>   psql.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
>   psql.cpp:46: error: 'PQescapeBytea' was not declared in this scope
>   psql.cpp:47: error: 'PQunescapeBytea' was not declared in this scope
>   make: *** [psql.o] Error 1
>   PostgreSQL disabled.
>   SQLite2 auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o sqlite2.o sqlite2.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   sqlite2.cpp:42:20: error: sqlite.h: No such file or directory
>   make: *** [sqlite2.o] Error 1
>   SQLite2 disabled.
>   unknown SQL driver: sqlite_symbian
>   TDS auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o tds.o tds.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   tds.cpp:42:22: error: sybfront.h: No such file or directory
>   tds.cpp:43:19: error: sybdb.h: No such file or directory
>   make: *** [tds.o] Error 1
>   TDS disabled.
>   NIS auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o nis.o nis.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -Wl,-O1 -o nis nis.o    -L/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/lib -lnsl 
>   /usr/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [nis] Error 1
>   NIS disabled.
>   Cups auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o cups.o cups.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   cups.cpp:42:23: error: cups/cups.h: No such file or directory
>   cups.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
>   cups.cpp:46: error: 'cups_dest_t' was not declared in this scope
>   cups.cpp:46: error: 'd' was not declared in this scope
>   cups.cpp:47: error: 'cupsGetDests' was not declared in this scope
>   make: *** [cups.o] Error 1
>   Cups disabled.
>   D-Bus auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o dbus.o dbus.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   dbus.cpp:43:23: error: dbus/dbus.h: No such file or directory
>   dbus.cpp:46:2: error: #error Needs at least dbus version 1
>   dbus.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
>   dbus.cpp:51: error: 'dbus_shutdown' was not declared in this scope
>   make: *** [dbus.o] Error 1
>   D-Bus disabled.
>   EGL (EGL/egl.h) auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o egl.o egl.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   egl.cpp:42:21: error: EGL/egl.h: No such file or directory
>   egl.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
>   egl.cpp:46: error: 'EGLint' was not declared in this scope
>   egl.cpp:46: error: expected `;' before 'x'
>   egl.cpp:47: error: 'EGLDisplay' was not declared in this scope
>   egl.cpp:47: error: expected`;' before 'dpy'
>   egl.cpp:48: error: 'EGLContext' was not declared in this scope
>   egl.cpp:48: error: expected `;' before 'ctx'
>   egl.cpp:49: error: 'dpy' was not declared in this scope
>   egl.cpp:49: error: 'ctx' was not declared in this scope
>   egl.cpp:49: error: 'eglDestroyContext' was not declared in this scope
>   make: *** [egl.o] Error 1
>   EGL (EGL/egl.h) disabled.
>   EGL (GLES/egl.h) auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0`pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`-c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o egl4gles1.o egl4gles1.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   egl4gles1.cpp:42:22: error: GLES/egl.h: No such file or directory
>   egl4gles1.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
>   egl4gles1.cpp:46: error: 'EGLint' was not declared in this scope
>   egl4gles1.cpp:46: error: expected`;' before 'x'
>   egl4gles1.cpp:47: error: 'EGLDisplay' was not declared in this scope
>   egl4gles1.cpp:47: error: expected `;' before 'dpy'
>   egl4gles1.cpp:48: error: 'EGLContext' was not declared in this scope
>   egl4gles1.cpp:48: error: expected`;' before 'ctx'
>   egl4gles1.cpp:49: error: 'dpy' was not declared in this scope
>   egl4gles1.cpp:49: error: 'ctx' was not declared in this scope
>   egl4gles1.cpp:49: error: 'eglDestroyContext' was not declared in this scope
>   make: *** [egl4gles1.o] Error 1
>   EGL (GLES/egl.h) disabled.
>   Glib auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o glib.o glib.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -Wl,-O1 -o glib glib.o    -L/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/lib
>
>   /usr/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [glib] Error 1
>   Glib disabled.
>   tslib auto-detection... ()
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -c -pipe -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++ -I. -I/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/include -o tslib.o tslib.cpp
>   cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -msoft-float -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -march=armv4 -mtune=arm920t -O0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -Wl,-O1 -o tslib tslib.o    -L/home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/tslib/lib -lts 
>   /usr/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [tslib] Error 1
>   tslib disabled.
>   The tslib functionality test failed!
>    You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing
>    QMAKE_INCDIR and QMAKE_LIBDIR in
>    /home/soroosh/soroosh/installation_files/arm_embedded/qt-everywhere/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++.

Comment: Try editing the error message to only the relevant parts.  What have you tried?  Do you have **EGL**?  Do you have **DBUS**?  Try to run `./configure -embedded arm -help` and *study* the options.  If you don't know what an option means, *google* it and find out if your *rootfs* supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it turned out tslib was not correctly insttalled